# How to set a pointer to a asciiz string in MIPS

Tags: assembly, input, mips

I am trying to convert a asciiz string the user inputs to an integer. This is the code I have so far. It works perfectly if I hard code a string and then use the command la $s1, hardCodedString. However when I try get user input, nothing is being printed. Is it because la is not the right command to use?

How should I store a pointer to the inputted asciiz string currently in $a0 in $s1?

```
.data   
theStr: .asciiz "Enter whatever it is: \n"
errorMessage1: .asciiz "Erroooor1\n"
errorMessage2: .asciiz "Erroooor2\n"
num: .asciiz "123"
input1: .space 10
.text
main:



la $a0, theStr #prints Enter
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 8 #read a string into a0
la $a0, input1
syscall


move $s1, $a0 #HERE IS THE LINE IN QUESTION
li $t0, 10
li $s2,0

lp:         
  lbu $t1, ($s1)       #load unsigned char from array into t1
  beq $t1, $0, FIN     #NULL terminator found
  blt $t1, 48, error   #check if char is not a digit (ascii<'0')
  bgt $t1, 57, error   #check if char is not a digit (ascii>'9')
  addi $t1, $t1, -48   #converts t1's ascii value to dec value
  mul $s2, $s2, $t0    #sum *= 10
  add $s2, $s2, $t1    #sum += array[s1]-'0'
  addi $s1, $s1, 1     #increment array address
  j lp                 #jump to start of loop

FIN:

move $a0, $s2
li $v0, 1
syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the syscall doesn't change `$a0` that instruction is fine. I have tested in spim, and there it stays unchanged. Otherwise you can simply reload it by `la $s1, input1`. Also note that the input string will have the newline in it, so your code will branch to the `error` label before it gets to the NULL terminator (if the input syscall even puts that into the buffer). I assume your `error` label, that you didn't show, will skip the printing. You should always show all the code.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting $a1 to the number of characters to read before syscall 8.

Answer (score 0):

You should load an immediate to $a1 to let the compiler know how many characters to read.
like this:

```
la $a0, input1
li $a1, 4  #The compiler will take the first 3 characters as input
li $v0, 8 #read a string into a0
syscall
```